# Невозможностью поднять бин из-за protected конструктора

Tags: spring, java

Здравствуйте. У меня такая ситуация - есть класс, в нем объявлен один `public` конструктор (без параметров) и один `protected` - c параметрами. Мне нужен тот, который `protected` c параметрами. Я наследуюсь от первоначального класса, в нем определяю `public` конструктор и оттуда вызываю `protected` конструктор базового класса, но Spring при подъеме моего бина (отнаследованного класса) ругается мол конструктор не `public`. Эту ситуацию можно как-то обойти?

Код:

```
public class MultiValueMapContainer extends MultiValueMap {
private int queueCapacity;

public MultiValueMapContainer(int queueCapacity) {
    super(new HashMap(), new InstantiateFactory(ArrayBlockingQueue.class,
            new Class[]{Integer.class}, new Object[]{queueCapacity}));
    this.queueCapacity = queueCapacity;
}

public int getQueueCapacity() {
    return queueCapacity;
}}
```

В `MultiValueMap`:

```
protected MultiValueMap(java.util.Map map, Factory collectionFactory)
```

У `InstantiateFactory` конструктор `public`:

```
<bean name="MyMap" class="package.MultiValueMapContainer">
    <constructor-arg type="int" value="${initialSeriesCount}"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: Можно попробовать создать приват метод вместо конструктора и обращаться к нему геттерами и сеттерами.

Comment: Тексту бы программного.
Обычно так использовать можно, если у вас:

    class A {
        protected A(int i){//...};
    }
    
    class B extends A {
        public B(int i){
            super(i); //work
            A a = new A(i); //fail
        };
    }

Comment: приведите общий код ваших конструкторов и конфигурацию контекста

Comment: У меня точно так же все сделанно - не работает
Обновил вопрос

Comment: Странно, упрощенный пример ваш работает замечательно. А точный текст ошибки можно?

Comment: @yozh прав, проблема где-то в параметрах функции, а не вашем классе.

Comment: Заработало с int.class, спасибо большое за помощь =)
Действительно: конструктор Queue принимает строго int, как то я не обратил на это особого внимания.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Integer.class` -> `int.class`

Причина: так как там внутри конструктора `InstantiateFactory`, очевидно, используется рефлексия, то параметры, указывающие типы аргументов конструктора должны быть точными - несмотря на то, что `int` можно автоупаковать в `Integer`, `int.class` никак не связан с `Integer.class`.

Comment: Спасибо. Не задумывался что при использовании рефлексии упаковки не канают. Ну оно в принципе и логично.